# Accessing object that is below a floating object

Tags: tableau-api

[Link to original post](https://community.tableau.com/message/669701#669701)

Here is what I am facing.

[image]   [image: Object behind floating object]

I am using the 'sheet selector' technique to switch between two sheets and the sheet selector parameter is the 'PY' and 'Date Range' option.
I also want to hide the corresponding filters along with the sheets.
When I pick PY - the checkboxes will be displayed.
When I pick date range Rebate Commit Date will be displayed.

I was able to successfully hide PY option by setting it to 'Only relevant values'.
However that is not working for date range

[image: Relevant values not working for date range]

So I used a floating object in a vertical container to hide the date range.
It is hiding successfully but when I need to access date range am not able to do that because of the floating object on top.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Answered in tableau community. Link - https://community.tableau.com/message/669701#669701

Answer (score 0):

Answered in tableau community - [Link](https://community.tableau.com/message/669701#669701)